# Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'loginCtrl>' is not a function got undefined

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, undefined

Hey guys i have been stuck with this for the past hour. So basically when you type in admin as username and admin as password in [this](http://elide.netne.net/#/) website it dosent go to the hash dashboard.html and shows an error in console and dosent go to the dashboard.html...

But it works on [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/mIOqvREdiS3tcatlr43i?p=preview)... Am i crazy?

Here is the code:

Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang= "en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Basic Login Form</title>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.8"></script>
    <script src = "https://rawgit.com/nirus/Angular-Route-Injector/master/dist/routeInjector.js"></script>
    <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app = "app">
  <div ng-view>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

dashboard.html:

```
Welcome User!
```

main.js:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])

app.config(function($routeProvider) {

  $routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'Login.html'

  })

  .when('/dashboard', {
    resolve: {
      "check": function($location, $rootScope) {
        if(!$rootScope.logedIn){
          location.path('/')
        }
        else{
          templateUrl: 'dashboard.html'
        }
      }

    },
    templateUrl: "dashboard.html"

  })

  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  })

})

app.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, $location, $rootScope) {
  $scope.submit = function() {

    if ($scope.username == 'admin' && $scope.password == 'admin') {
     $rootScope.logedIn = true;
      $location.path('/dashboard')

    }

  }

})
```

Login.html:

```
<div ng-controller = "loginCtrl">
  <form action = "/" id = "myLogin">
    UserName : <input type = "text" name = "username" id = "username" ng-model = "username"><br>
    Password : <input type = "text" name = "password" id = "password" ng-model = "password"><br>
    <button type="button" ng-click = "submit()">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: did you had any issues reported on console.. check it by doing F12... mostly your path of main.js would be an issue..

Comment: Have you defined ng-app="app" in your html to include the app ?

Comment: Yes i did. I gave you the website. You can check it to...

Comment: @DagmFekadu you didnt have to according to this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DHqHynuLXRE&list=PLYxzS__5yYQmX2bItSRCqwiQZn5dIL1gt&index=15

Comment: @DagmFekadu 5:20 is where he got his results in that link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked your site you have not put the controller properly,

Change

**From:**

```
ng-controller="loginCtrl>"
```

**To:**

```
ng-controller="loginCtrl">
```

Comment: What in the world. I DONT have that in my code editor... I littterarly edited my website and still the same

Comment: where you have hosted this? what os?

Comment: From 000webhost.com . Uploaded new file to filzilla. And its still dosent work ... ><

Answer (score 0):

if you inspect the code... you will see below

```
   ng-controller="loginCtrl>"
```

remove the `>` symbol at the end

[image]

Comment: I am inspecting the website link you provided

Comment: What in the world. I DONT have that in my code editor... I littterarly edited my website and still the same

Answer (score 0):

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
```

$routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'Login.html'

})

In your code while loading your partial html,you forgot to include the controller 
so should be like this

```
                $routeProvider.when('/', {
              templateUrl: 'Login.html',
              controller:'loginCtrl'

            })
```

Your final code looks like

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])

      app.config(function($routeProvider) {

        $routeProvider.when('/', {
          templateUrl: 'Login.html',
          controller: 'loginCtrl'

        })

        .when('/dashboard', {
          resolve: {
            "check": function($location, $rootScope) {
              if(!$rootScope.logedIn){
                location.path('/')
              }
              else{
                templateUrl: 'dashboard.html'
              }
            }

          },
          templateUrl: "dashboard.html"

        })

        .otherwise({
          redirectTo: '/'
        })

      })

      app.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, $location, $rootScope) {
        $scope.submit = function() {

          if ($scope.username == 'admin' && $scope.password == 'admin') {
           $rootScope.logedIn = true;
            $location.path('/dashboard')

          }

        }

      })
```

Comment: why didnt he do this in this tutorial though?] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DHqHynuLXRE&list=PLYxzS__5yYQmX2bItSRCqwiQZn5dIL1gt&index=15

Comment: I didn't watch the video but he may have reasons, may be he have modules that you don't included try that on every partial view

Comment: If you have no angular code on the partial,you can skip a controller but here you have used angular code in the partial so it needs a controller

Comment: try other answers in combination with this one,should work for you